# Is there a keyboard shortcut for %*% and %o% operators?

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts

In R we can do inner matrix multiplication with `%*%` and outer multiplication with `%o%`.
Is there any keyboard shortcut for each of them?

Comment: Just curious: these are already pretty short. You want something with **fewer** characters? Any particular reason why?  (Code golf?) I suspect this is going to be impossible because of parser constraints ...

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to type these operators faster. Like for operator ```%>%``` there is Ctrl+Shift+M for Windows. And for these 2 operators have not found anything...

Comment: I see; you're looking for a **keyboard shortcut**.  You'd have to specify what R interface you're using (my guess is RStudio?) ... the answer is probably here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

These are already pretty short but if you are willing to write the expressions as a string and then write a function to translate that to R and run it then one character short forms could be used.

```
run <- function(s, mul = "@", out = "#", envir = parent.frame(), verbose = FALSE) {
  ss <- gsub(out, "%o%", gsub(mul, "%*%", s, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
  if (verbose) print(ss)
  eval(parse(text = ss), envir)
}

v <- 1:3

run("t(v) @ (v # v) @ v")
```

There are also numerous utilities that allow one to use pre-specified keystrokes to insert defined text.  This would depend on your operating system but on Windows here is a list of such utilities: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/insert-text-commands-easily-quicktextpaste/  Depending on which editor you are using it may also have such capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a shortcut when writing, you can use RStudio snippets.
Go to Tools > Global Options > Code > Edit snippets
and then you can do something like

```r
snippet pprod
    ${1:X} %*% ${2:Y}
```

Then, in your script when you will write `pprod`, just like when using `library` or the `if` function, you have it automatically showing up.

Bonus: using tab you can switch from X to Y and replace with the names you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shrtcts](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/shrtcts/) package for this task. It lets you assign Keyboard Shortcuts to arbitrary `R` Code.

1. Use the command `shrtcts::edit_shortcuts()` in the RStudio Console to open the file where you define your custom shortcuts.
2. Paste the following code inside that file (set your preferred keybinding in the `@shortcut` line):

   ```
   #' Insert %*% Operator
   #'
   #' @description Insert %*% Operator at current Cursor Location
   #' @interactive
   #' @shortcut Cmd+R
   function() {
     rstudioapi::insertText(" %*% ") |>
       capture.output() |>
       invisible()
   }
   ```
3. Use the command `shrtcts::add_rstudio_shortcuts(set_keyboard_shortcuts = TRUE)` in the RStudio Console to add the new shortcut with its assigned keybinding. Then restart RStudio.

Now pressing e.g. `cmd+r` inserts the mutiplication operator surrounded by single spaces.
If you do not like the spaces, simply remove them inside the `rstudioapi::insertText()` function.

Analogously, you can create a separate shortcut for `%o%` (or really pretty much anything).